# How to send multiple images to Firebase and retrieve them in the UIImageView in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, file-upload, uiimageview

I have an app that lets users choose multiple images. The problem is that  it doesn't upload and save the image to the user in Firebase and retrieve the image.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

import Photos
import Firebase
import BSImagePicker

class Downloadimages: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
var PhotoArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func addImagesClicked(_ sender: Any) {




    // create an instance
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()

    //display picture gallery
    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
                                         select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        // User deselected an assets.

    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        // User cancelled. And this where the assets currently selected.
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        // User finished with these assets
        for i in 0..<assets.count
        {
            self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])

        }

        self.convertAssetToImages()

    }, completion: nil)

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
           image.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
               image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

               image.allowsEditing = false

               self.present(image, animated: true)
               {
                   //after its completed
               }
           }


           @objc(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
           {
               if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
               {
                   imgView.image = image

               }
               else
               {
                   //error
               }

               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

               let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
               if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imgView.image!){
                   storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
                       {
                           (metadata, error) in
                           if error != nil {
                               print("error")
                               return
                           }

                           print(metadata!)

              //how do I put the download URL in the metadata into my database

                   }
                   )
               }

           }





func convertAssetToImages() -> Void {

    if SelectedAssets.count != 0{


        for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count{

            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true


            manager.requestImage(for: SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                thumbnail = result!

            })

            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
            let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)


            self.PhotoArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)

        }

        self.imgView.animationImages = self.PhotoArray
        self.imgView.animationDuration = 3.0
        self.imgView.startAnimating()

    }


    print("complete photo array \(self.PhotoArray)")
}
```

}
and this is my post code

import Foundation

class Post {
    var id:String
    var author:UserProfile
    var text:String
    var createdAt:Date

```
init(id:String, author:UserProfile,text:String,timestamp:Double) {
    self.id = id
    self.author = author
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
}

static func parse(_ key:String, _ data:[String:Any]) -> Post? {

    if let author = data["author"] as? [String:Any],
        let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
        let username = author["username"] as? String,
        let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
        let url = URL(string:photoURL),
        let text = data["text"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {

        let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid, username: username, photoURL: url)
        return Post(id: key, author: userProfile, text: text, timestamp:timestamp)

    }

    return nil
}
```

}
this is my userProfile

import Foundation

class UserProfile {
    var uid:String
    var username:String
    var photoURL:URL

```
init(uid:String, username:String,photoURL:URL) {
    self.uid = uid
    self.username = username
    self.photoURL = photoURL
}
```

}

and this is

import Foundation

import Firebase

class UserService {

```
static var currentUserProfile:UserProfile?

static func observeUserProfile(_ uid:String, completion: @escaping ((_ userProfile:UserProfile?)->())) {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")

    userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var userProfile:UserProfile?

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any],
            let username = dict["username"] as? String,
            let photoURL = dict["photoURL"] as? String,
            let url = URL(string:photoURL) {

            userProfile = UserProfile(uid: snapshot.key, username: username, photoURL: url)
        }

        completion(userProfile)
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. A few issues with the question. 1) There's nothing in that code the uploads the image to Firebase 2) PhotoArray is a class var and when the viewController is dismissed/closes, that var will go out of scope 3) It's unclear what *it is not saved in the UIImage* means. Saved in the UIImage? Can you please clarify what your asking as well as what the specific issue is and add the appropriate code. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), fix the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: i did fix the question would you take a look

Comment: The question is still unclear and the presented code appears to be unrelated to what's asked. The problem described in the question is *it is not saved in the UIImage* - we don't really know what that means. As I mentioned in my first comment the statement is unclear and there's nothing in the code that would save a UIImage. Also, in the code we see you're populating a var `userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile` and then updating its properties `userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString` but there's no indication where `.photoURL.absoluteString` comes from. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: i just update it

Comment: I see this comment *//how do I put the download URL in the metadata into my database* in your question. Are you asking how to store data in the Real Time Database? Reviewing the guide [Uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) is a good place to start. Looking at the guide, within the closure of this function `riversRef.downloadURL { (url` you'll have access to the downloadURL. Then refer to [Basic Write Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write) on storing the value in the database.